# Speeding up block of code in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, scipy

I have identified two potential reasons why the following code snippet is performing very poorly, given points is a list of 10000 size-2 lists.

1. "append" to add new values given a key
2. The neighbour map dictionary.

   ```
   def calculate_distance(point1, point2):
     a = (point1[0], point1[1])
     b = (point2[0], point2[1])
     return distance.euclidean(a, b)

   def get_eps_neighbours(points, eps):
     neighbours = {}
     index = 0
     for p in points:
       for q in points:
           if(calculate_distance(p, q) <= eps):
               if index in neighbours:
                   neighbours[index].append(q)
               else:
                   neighbours[index] = q
       index = index + 1
   return {'neighbours': neighbours}
   ```

Any suggestions on how I can improve the code's efficiency?

Comment: is `point1` always a list of length 2, like `[1, 3]`? Why must it be converted to tuple before call to `euclidean`?

Comment: Use numpy arrays for this kind of computations.

Comment: If the code is working, try [codereview.se]

Comment: Euclidean distance performs a square root, but you could compare the square with the square of `eps`: `a ** 2 + b ** 2 <= eps ** 2`

Comment: Are you sure the code works? `neighbours[index] = q` isn't a `list`, but then you say `neighbours[index].append(q)`

Comment: You need to compare only with points after the current point `p`.

Comment: q is a list; to avoid  the infamous "KeyError 0 " problem, I do neighbours[index]  = q. When there is a key, I do the append. I have to compare with all points. That is the algorithm.

Comment: But you will end up with a `list` with the first two items coordinates, and the rest points: `[p0, q0, [p1, q1], [p2, q2]]`, rather than a list of points: `[[p0, q0], [p1, q1], [p2, q2]]`.

Comment: @PeterWood, Oh I see! My end result is a list of points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all combinations of points with each other. You can use [**`itertools.combinations`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Since we're making only the combinations we need, we don't need to keep looking up the dictionary index to append. We can keep the point and its list of neighbours together.

Using a [**`defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with a `list` means we don't have to manually create the `list` the first time we look up a point.

Also, you don't actually want the value of the euclidian distance, you just want to know if it is less than some other value. So comparing the squares will give you the same result.

To use a `point` as a key to a dictionary it needs to be immutable, so we convert it to a tuple:

```
def distance_squared(a, b):
    diff = complex(*a) - complex(*b)
    return diff.real ** 2 + diff.imag ** 2

from itertools import combinations
from collections import defaultdict

neighbours = defaultdict(list)
eps_squared = eps ** 2

point_neighbours = ((point, neighbours[tuple(point)]) for point in points)

for (p, p_neighbours), (q, _) in combinations(point_neighbours , r=2):
    if distance_squared(p, q) <= eps_squared:
        p_neighbours.append(q)
```

Comment: I am seeing a `Required argument 'r' (pos 2) not found` error when I tried to integrate the snippet in my code. If possible, can you rewrite the snippet using the two functions in the original question?

Comment: @envy_intelligence SO is not a code writing service. Learn to look at the documentation and understand errors. I'd missed the parameter `r` in the [**`combinations`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function. I've fixed the code, note the extra parentheses around the first argument to make it a generator.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So point is of list type which is not hashable. Can you comment on the same?

Comment: Sorry, keys to dictionaries need to be immutable. I've changed the code to convert the `list` to a `tuple`. Also I've put the generator of points and neighbours into a separate variable to be more readable. The line was getting too long (c:

Comment: Thank you. I apologize if I had miscommunicated my clarifications earlier.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of **trivially parallel** problem.

My recommendation:

- use `numpy`
- create 2 points^points matrices (2D-arrays), one for `x` another for `y`
- use `numpy`'s array arithmetic

Example:

```
In [52]: points = [(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4)]  # super-simple data

In [54]: Xb = numpy.repeat(numpy.array(points)[:,0], 4).reshape(4, 4)

In [60]: Xb
Out[60]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4]])

In [61]: Xa = numpy.tile(numpy.array(points)[:,0], 4).reshape(4, 4)

In [62]: Xa
Out[62]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])

# Yb = numpy.repeat(numpy.array(points)[:,1], 4).reshape(4, 4)
# Ya = numpy.tile(numpy.array(points)[:,1], 4).reshape(4, 4)

In [65]: D = ((Xa - Xb) ** 2 + (Ya - Yb) ** 2) ** 0.5

In [66]: D
Out[66]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  1.41421356,  2.82842712,  4.24264069],
       [ 1.41421356,  0.        ,  1.41421356,  2.82842712],
       [ 2.82842712,  1.41421356,  0.        ,  1.41421356],
       [ 4.24264069,  2.82842712,  1.41421356,  0.        ]])

In [71]: D < 2
Out[71]: 
array([[ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)

# Assuming you want only one copy from each pair (a,b), (b,a)
In [73]: triangle = numpy.tri(4, 4, -1, bool)

In [74]: triangle
Out[74]: 
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)

In [76]: neighbours = (D < 2) * triangle  # multiplication for "logical and"
Out[76]: 
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)

# Neighbours' x and y coordinates are available so:
In [107]: numpy.compress(neighbours.flatten(), Xa.flatten())
Out[107]: array([1, 2, 3])

# Indices to elements in original `points` list like this:
Indexb = numpy.repeat(numpy.arange(4), 4).reshape(4, 4)
Indexa = numpy.tile(numpy.arange(4), 4).reshape(4, 4)
numpy.transpose([numpy.compress(neighbours.flatten(), Indexa.flatten()),
                 numpy.compress(neighbours.flatten(), Indexb.flatten())])
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3]])
```

Comment: Interesting, could be so kind and elaborate more on this? I'm trying to remember my algebraic courses, but nothing can come to my mind in term of calculating euclidean distance using matrices.

Comment: Matrix is only permutation of all points x all points. Euclidean distance is still calculated for each pair. It's a lot faster because you let numpy do it for you :)

Comment: P.S. I'm a little rusty with `numpy`, I welcome ideas to simplify this flow.

Answer (score 1):

With general idea of your algorithm, I think you may reduce the list of points that undergo *euclidean distance test* by first removeing (or copying to another list) only elements which `2*abs(p.x - q.x) <= eps` (repeat for y), that would be much faster than calculating euclidean for all points. If `eps` is small that would work.

Comment: Hmm... more I'm thinking about it, the more I sure you don't need multiplication by 2, as if the distance along one dimension is longer than `eps`, euclidean distance cannot be smaller, as this is works like radius.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will speed up your code but the pythonic way of counting loops is like this:

```
for i, p in enumerate(points):
```

Also - I'm not sure I understand the logic of searching through the whole dictionary (map) keys every time. This bit of code doesn't look like its doing something useful

```
neighBourMap[index] = q
```

This adds a key value pair of key: q, value: q to the dictionary. Have you tried just using a list instead i.e.

```
neighBourMap = []
```

Comment: I need an index to be the key to a list of lists. Just using a list would not help  my case.

Comment: @nrob `index` is an integer starting counting at zero.

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers are correct, but they won't give you a huge speedup. Using numpy arrays will give you a little bit of speedup, parallelizing will give you a speedup. But the speedup will be not enought, if you have 1 million points and you still use your current algorithms, which does n^2 distance calculations. (1 million)^2 is way to many. If your using numpy or not?

You should switch your algorithm. You should store your points in a k-d tree. This way you can concentrate your search to a few neighbor candidates. Instead of iterating over all points `q`, you can simply iterate over all points `q` with `|q.x - p.x| < eps and |q.y - p.y| < eps`. If your `eps` is small and there are only a few neighbors for each point, than this should speed you up quite a lot.

Here's a pdf, that describes the algorithm how to find all points in a certain range: http://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/CS302/Handouts/kdtree.pdf

Comment: Nice thing, but building a tree is quite complex process and worth the effort if you data set is relatively constant.

Comment: @user38034, perhaps you can add a heuristic when K-D tree is beneficial? Surely it's not for large accepted distance..

Answer (score 0):

For one thing you can replace

```
index in neighBourMap.keys()):`
```

with just

```
index in neighBourMap
```

which will run faster as a copy of the dictionary's key does not need to be created.

Better yet, use a [`defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) which obviates the need for checking for a key before appending to the list value.